# Upgraded to 17.04 and now spacebar wont work

Tags: unity, keyboard, do-release-upgrade, 17.04

I've found that the problem only happens on lightdm as I was able to see it working on the text tty.

Here's what `xev` says:

```
KeymapNotify event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

`xinput` reports the key as:

```
 key press   65 
 key release 65
```

So far I'm using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +<kbd>C</kbd> to make it work

Also I've found that some actions that use the key, like <kbd>Alt</kbd> +<kbd>Space</kbd> , work just fine but not when using the key by itself; all it does is just clears the text selection (or the cursor on the command line) when pressed and returns to what it was on key release, if that makes any sense.

Any idea what this could be?

In the meantime I'll be using `.Xmopmap` to use the right-control as a space:

```
keysym Control_R = space
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>I've found a workaround.</strike>

1. Boot the machine as always
2. Switch to text mode console, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>
3. Login as your user
4. Execute: `unity --reset`

Not really sure why but when unity reset itself the spacebar is working as always.

**Update: Oct 2018**: So the workaround wont work anymore and after some debugging I've found that `ibus-ui-gtk3` was the one breaking the spacebar. Simply killing the process will make the spacebar actually work again. I've removed the package since I no need multiple language input methods.

```
sudo apt remove ibus-gtk3
```

Comment: Simply out of interest: How did you debug that ? I had the same problem 30 minutes ago.

Comment: Life saver, thanks